# What is the efficient way to find the top-most images of a Landsat-8 mosaic with latest data on top?

Tags: geometry, intersection, landsat, mosaic, landsat-8

I'm building a simple mosaic of Landsat-8 for a region of interest (a bounding box) for a time period, so that the latest data would be put on top of the mosaic. I've found 100 scenes with cloud cover from 0 to 5% that intersect with the ROI, so I have a list of 100 unique geometries, sorted by an acquisition date. Now I want to determine which scenes are "on top" of the mosaic in order not to download the scenes that won't be visible. I wonder what is the most efficient way to find the top-most geometries with the least number of intersections? The difficulty is that I've sorted images by cloud cover, so now some images in strips are missing

Comment: If you have an earth engine account, check example algorithms. There is an example doing exactly what you want to obtain (in ImageCollection section)

Comment: @aldo_tapia, I don't have an account yet, but I believe here's the example https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_composite_mosaic . I'm interested in algorithm rather than implementation. Maybe there is an open source solution?

Comment: you can do it in R for example, masking by QA band and sorting by relative area of this mask. But you need to download all scenes to select the best one, thats is why GEE is a great option. You can sort by cloud cover, mask by cloud score and fill cloud holes with other scenes. Finally, you can download the output mosaic. I my opinion, is the best plataform to perform your task

Comment: Also, [check this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/302589628_Generating_a_cloud-free_homogeneous_Landsat-8_mosaic_of_Switzerland_using_Google_Earth_Engine). Contains the necessary code to reproduce it for your purposes